# How to specify the items in reference list using BibTeX? ChemPhysChem LaTeX requirement

Tags: reference, latex, bibtex, biblatex

I'm revising a manuscript for *ChemPhysChem*. They just provided a very simple templet [here](https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/hub/journal/14397641/latex-guidelines). However, I have some problems meeting the requirement:

> Please follow our house style for references for example: [1] X. Y.
> Name, A. B. Name, J. Abbr. 2016, 5, 111-120.

This kind of reference hides the title, and I can not find an [existing style](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles) to meet the need.

I am using the following latex script:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref_r.bib}
```

What do I need to do to solve the problem? Do I really need to build a new `.bst` file? Could anyone share their experience on submitting manuscripts on *ChemPhysChem* using LaTeX?

Comment: Did you check with the publisher that they actually accept bib**la**tex references? Not many publishers do and their template uses bibtex instead

Comment: The templet they provide uses BibTeX.  And in the comment of the templet,  it even says "no packages, no newly defined commands". @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bib**la**tex for journal submissions unless your publisher explicitly states that they do accept it. While it is a nice and flexible tool, biblatex is not yet the standard.

---

Just follow the instructions from the template and use

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%alternatively you may use

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mymanuscript.bib}

%and send the .bib file along with your manuscript

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Don't worry if the resulting style might be a bit different from their requirement, they won't use it anyway but convert your source files with their pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

I changed to my latex using BibTeX back, and built a `cpc.bst` [file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/HuangJiaLian/DataBase0@master/uPic/2021_10_16_17_cpc.bst) for *ChemPhysChem* using the following command with the help of the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWgf1CPfUFc):

```sh
latex makebst
```

It would not be that hard to create the bibliography style file using the guide of the above-mentioned video.

And the result looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP35y.png).